# Elementary Number pattern

Tags: number-sequence

$$\begin{align}
4&\qquad6\\
&\,\diagdown\diagup\\
&\;\;\,8\\
\\
6&\quad\;\;18\\
&\,\diagdown\diagup\\
&\;\,27\\
\\
10&\quad\;\;\,16\\
&\diagdown\diagup\\
&\;\;x\\
\end{align}$$

The question is an easy one. You have to find $x$.

Comment: You know you can delete your own posts right?

Comment: You can also edit the post to fix the problem.

Comment: It is unclear what the slashes represent - are these also missing numbers? or mathematical symbols? or something else (e.g. scores from ten-pin bowling)? Does the puzzle consist of three sequences in rows, or is it an acrostic (arrangement in columns is also significant)?

Answer (score 2):

To me the pattern appears to be as follows:

> Multiply the first two numbers and divide by the third number (to which the two lines lead). In the first case, this operation gives 3 ($4 \times 6 \div 8$). In the second line, it gives 4 ($6 \times 18 \div 27$). So moving forward, I'd expect the next line to give a result of 5 from this operation. So $10 \times 16 \div 32 = 5$.

So I believe $x$ should be

> 32

Answer (score 0):

> I am going to go ahead and say X is 125 as in the other cases the bottom value is equal to one half of the top left value cubed.

A clear flaw is the lack of incorporating the top right value but it is completely viable to assume it could be a red herring.

Comment: 1. There is some ambiguity in "half of the top left value cubed".   
2. [This problem](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/22277/elementary-number-sequence) is apparently from a 5th grade math book, so red herrings and cubed halves probably aren't the way to go.

Comment: hide the answer please

Answer (score 0):

> x is 32 
>  
>  It looks like the bottom number of each "triplet" is generated from a 
>  multiplication of the most common prime in the above two numbers in the prime 
>  E.g. 4 and 6 is 2x 2 and 2 x 3 so taking the 2's we have 2x2x2 = 8
>  E.g. 6 and 18 is 2 x 3 and 2 x 3 x 3 so taking the 3's we have 3x3x3 = 27
>  Finally 10 and 16 is 2x 5 and 2 x 2 x 2 x2 so taking the 2's we have 2x2x2x2x2 = 32